# convert strings in separate lists to unicode - python

Tags: python, list, unicode

What's the best way to convert every string in a list (containing other lists) to unicode in python?

For example:

```
[['a','b'], ['c','d']]
```

to

```
[[u'a', u'b'], [u'c', u'd']]
```

Comment: Is your list specifically always a list of lists of strings, or is the nesting arbitrary?

Comment: There are two halves of this question. First, there's "how do I convert a string to Unicode". And if you don't think that's a real question, you definitely need to read Horner6's answer. Second, there's, "assuming I know how I want to convert each string to Unicode, how do I map it across this data structure". If that's the only part you're asking, it would be clearer to show how you want to convert each string.

Comment: @Peter DeGlopper: yes, it's always a list of lists of strings

Comment: @user2635863 In python, strings are arrays of bytes. You need to know which encoding they are before you "decode" them into a Unicode structure.

Comment: I want to use non-english characters, that's why I'd like to convert everything to unicode.

Comment: The point is that there are multiple incompatible ways to represent characters (especially non-English characters, but UTF-16 for just one example represents English characters differently than ASCII) in byte strings, and you have to know how your input is encoded before you can decode it into unicode.

Comment: If you convert English characters to Unicode, you just have English characters in Unicode. If you have non-English characters in your byte-strings, you have to know what encoding they're in. (Also, if those strings are originally literals in your source, why not just make them Unicode literals in the first place, and don't even bother with converting?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> li = [['a','b'], ['c','d']]

>>> [[v.decode("UTF-8") for v in elem] for elem in li]
[[u'a', u'b'], [u'c', u'd']]
```

Comment: I think it was better before you added the "with unicode() function" part. That's almost always the wrong thing to do, and your original answer was dead-simple and near-perfect.

Comment: @abarnert. Can you explain little further? Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: My understanding was that the unicode constructor implicitly decoded. I'm curious to see if there's a difference too.

Comment: Your first edit did `unicode(v)`. The difference is obvious: that's using the default encoding, which is usually 'ascii', and almost always wrong. Your second edit changed it to `unicode(v, "UTF-8")`, which is functionally equivalent to the `decode` call—a bit less clear, and not future-compatible to 3.x, but not actually _bad_. But I was responding to the first edit.

Comment: @abarnert. Yeah I read that `unicode()` is not there in `3.x`, so removed it. But, may be I'll add it and make a note of it.

Comment: @RohitJain: There's really no advantage to using the two-argument form of `unicode`. It's less obvious that it's decoding, it's not forward-compatible, it's not reversible (there's no two-argument `str` or `bytes`), it puts the focus on the wrong thing, it's easier to get wrong (e.g., by forgetting the codec), it's even more keystrokes. So… why not just stick with `.decode()`?

Comment: @abarnert. I see. Ok. I'll rather remove it. :)

Comment: I'd prefer `decode` too, but to be fair you can also forget to specify the encoding with `decode`.  `'foo'.decode()` works fine, though obviously it won't if the bytes include values not handled by the default encoding.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: Oops, you're right, I forgot that the proposal to make that an error in 2.7 was rejected…

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy answer with unicode. But fortunately, once you understand it, it'll carry with you to other programming languages.

This is, by far, the best resource that I've seen for python unicode:

http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html

Use the arrow keys (on your keyboard) to navigate to the next and previous slides.

Also, please take a look at this (and the other links from the end of that slideshow).

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: What if the strings are "Windows-1252" encoded byte strings? Decoding by guessing that they're UTF-8 is not going to help him. The only thing that will help is a fundamental understanding of text encoding so that he can manage the input and produce an expected result.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: The two of you have just made different guesses on which half of this problem is the hard part that the OP was (or should have been) asking about. Until we get some clarification from the OP, there's probably not much point arguing about it.

Comment: Well, basically I just want to add the "u" letter before each string so that I can use non-english characters. As far as I'm aware the UTF-8 is the character set I should use.

Comment: @user2635863: The way you're saying that strongly implies that you should go read that set of slides. (Sorry I couldn't think of a way to fit an Arrested Development/Pop-Pop joke…)

Comment: "As far as I'm aware" is exactly my point. Unicode is not something that is necessarily straight forward. If you read each of the slides and read Joel's article, that should be enough background information for you to confidently interpret text in any encoding.

Comment: Also, you need to understand the difference between string values and string literals/displays. Adding a `u` to the start of the string "abc" just gives you the string "uabc"; it doesn't give you the unicode string u"abc". The `u` isn't part of the string any more than the quotes are.

Comment: @abarnert: yes, I'm aware of that. The program I'm using just accepts unicode strings. By adding the u seems to solve the problems I was having with saving non-english characters. I also added this line at the beginning of the program # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-, so that's why I'm assuming the character set should be UTF-8.

Comment: @user2635863: That affects the string literals in your source code. It doesn't affect anything else, like strings you read from user input or files. (And if you're trying to change the literals in your source, just put the `u` prefixes on all the literals; don't create narrow literals and decode them after the fact.)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [['a','b'], ['c','d']]
>>> map(lambda x: map(unicode, x), l)
[[u'a', u'b'], [u'c', u'd']]
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, unless the OP really wants to decode with `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. And fixing it to take the encoding means either a lambda inside the lambda, or a partial inside the lambda; either way, I think it's much simpler to use a comprehension here.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I'll leave it here in case of the OP  wants to go with `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, and it looks nice and clear.